# How to check for 2 conditional statements where both must be met, while looping through each row in database array? PHP / MySql

Tags: php, arrays, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I will do my best to articulate the problem.

I am checking for duplicates on an Insert statement by placing the query into an array and using a While loop to check each row in the database table. I have the logic working except it's still giving me the error when **only one** of the conditions is met in any row. What I'm looking for is how to produce the error **only when both are met for any single row**.

Example: An artist can have multiple songs, but I don't want them to have duplicate songs. Meanwhile multiple artists should be able to have songs with the same title. However, I'm getting the error even if one of the conditions is true in any row, preventing me from accomplishing this.

So, how do I check both conditions to be met for a single row and not across multiple rows.

Thanks!

```
// Insert user input Music into the Database 
// Check for duplicates
public function insertMusic() {
   $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
            or die('Error connecting to DB');

   $song_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($this->song_title));    
   $song_length = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($this->song_length));  
   $song_album = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($this->song_album));
   $song_artist = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($this->song_artist));
   $album_art = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($this->album_art));

   // Check database for duplicates
   $duplicate_query = "Select * from Music";
   $duplicate_results = mysqli_query($dbc, $duplicate_query)
           or die('Error querying DB');
   $isDuplicate = true;

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($duplicate_results)) {
       // Something with these 2 conditions are the issue??
       if ( ($song_title != $row['SongTitle']) && ($song_artist != $row['SongArtist']) ) {
            $isDuplicate = false;
       } else {
            $isDuplicate = true;
            echo '<p class="error">Song is already in the Database!</p>';
            break;
       }
   }

   if ($isDuplicate === false) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO Music (id, dateAdded, SongTitle, SongLength, SongAlbum, SongArtist, AlbumArt)" .
                   "VALUES (0, NOW(), '$song_title', '$song_length', '$song_album', '$song_artist', '$album_art')";

        // echo $query;

        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
                 or die('Error querying DB 1');

        mysqli_close($dbc);

        echo '<p class="success">Success!</p>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking if a song exists based on a query that runs on ALL the data added to the table `Music` instead of just check against the possible existing data?. I mean, run a `SELECT * FROM Music WHERE SongTitle = '$song_title' AND SongArtist = '$song_artist'` And with this SELECT if something is returned you know it exists, if not, then, it doesn't and you don't leave the check on a logic like that because if you have like 100,000 rows this is going to take A LOT of time...

Comment: @Asfo Good point, this sounds much more efficient (still kind of new to php). I plugged that in to my `$duplicate_query`... Still unsure of what additional steps I need to take to solve my issue

Comment: Technically to solve this, you just need to check `mysqli_num_rows` function, if its more than 0 it means you already have it, if not, then you don't. And that's it.

Comment: @Asfo that worked! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should looks like this at the end (not tested):

```
// Insert user input Music into the Database 
// Check for duplicates
public function insertMusic() {
   $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
            or die('Error connecting to DB');

   $song_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($this->song_title));    
   $song_length = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($this->song_length));  
   $song_album = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($this->song_album));
   $song_artist = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($this->song_artist));
   $album_art = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($this->album_art));

   // Check database for duplicates
   $duplicate_query = "SELECT * FROM Music WHERE SongTitle = '$song_title' AND SongArtist = '$song_artist'";
   $duplicate_results = mysqli_query($dbc, $duplicate_query)
           or die('Error querying DB');
   $isDuplicate = false;

   if(mysqli_num_rows($duplicate_results) > 0) {
     $isDuplicate = true;
   }

   if ($isDuplicate === false) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO Music (id, dateAdded, SongTitle, SongLength, SongAlbum, SongArtist, AlbumArt)" .
                   "VALUES (0, NOW(), '$song_title', '$song_length', '$song_album', '$song_artist', '$album_art')";

        // echo $query;

        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
                 or die('Error querying DB 1');

        mysqli_close($dbc);

        echo '<p class="success">Success!</p>';
   }
}
```

Comment: could just use `$isDuplicate = mysqli_num_rows($duplicate_results) > 0;` which will evaluate as true/false.

Comment: thanks! I used something similar and it works great! just modified some of the booleans

Comment: @fyrye I know, but, I just give the OP the idea, I think he can do a refactoring on the code later to make it smaller.

Answer (score 0):

As stated there's no need to iterate over the entire table recordset. It is far more efficient to simply ask the table if the value exists, using `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE criteria)`.

I believe the `INSERT SET id = 0`, may be another issue you are experiencing. I presume the `id` column is an auto-increment primary key, and would introduce a *duplicate entry error* if an already existing `id` value is specified. When the `id` is omitted from your `INSERT` statement, MySQL will automatically set the column to the incremented `id` value.

I also added some `__LINE__` entries to your error trapping, to help in debugging, however I suggest that you invest into using [`Exceptions` and handling them](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) and using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), to prevent SQL Injection attacks.

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
        or die('Error connecting to DB ' . __LINE__);

$song_title = trim($this->song_title);    
$song_artist = trim($this->song_artist);
$song_length = trim($this->song_length);
$song_album = trim($this->song_album);
$album_art = trim($this->album_art);

//determine if duplicate
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, 'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Music 
WHERE SongTitle = ? AND SongArtist = ?)');
if (!$stmt) {
       die('An error occurred ' . __LINE__);
}
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $song_title, $song_artist);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $isDuplicate);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
$stmt = null;

if (!$isDuplicate) {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, 
    'INSERT INTO Music (dateAdded, SongTitle, SongLength, SongAlbum, SongArtist, AlbumArt)
VALUES (NOW(), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
    if (!$stmt) {
       die('An error occurred ' . __LINE__);
    }
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssss', $song_title, $song_length, $song_album, $song_artist, $album_art);
    if (false === mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
       die('An error occurred ' . __LINE__);
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    $stmt = null;
    echo '<p class="success">Success!</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p class="error">Song is already in the Database!</p>';
}
mysqli_close($dbc);
```